# Setting the account "Run as administrator" uses

Tags: windows-7, administrator

How do I set the account "Run as administrator" uses? It doesn't seem to just use the one called "Administrator" which I have created (this is a work computer that I didn't set up).

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in with an account with admin privileges, then obviously it uses your current account.

If you are logged in with a standard user account, it should prompt you with a list of admin accounts.

Comment: It doesn't prompt me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from some other answers it seems that "Run as Administrator" actually runs with the current account, but gives it the full permissions of the current acount rather than a reduced set.

Useful answers:

- https://superuser.com/a/492979/80582
- https://superuser.com/a/107404/80582

There was another useful one but I lost it. I believe the reason it doesn't prompt me for an account is because the UAC settings have been changed (I haven't checked but that seems the likeliest cause).

Answer (score -1):

"Run as Administrator" runs as the account you are signed in as, I do not believe Windows has such a feature to change how this feature works.

Comment: I believe the "Administrator" account has been removed from my machine - or at least it isn't in ADUC. Are you sure there really is a special Administrator account? Are you sure you aren't just thinking of the *default* administrator account?

Comment: @Timmmm - There is indeed an account called Administrator and unless its been diabled it exists.  Even if you could change it, it would require you to be an Administator on the domain, to change it.

Comment: To elaborate on: "When you click 'Run as Administrator' you are actually running the program as this special unimpeded 'Administrator' account." This is not what it is running it as, it runs it as the currently logged in admin, with that accounts assigned permissions. As for: "A lot of services or systems may also run under this hidden account to handle important services that normal users may not be allowed to run at all." It is **NOT** running it as the default admin account, rather services are run as the hidden user that nobody can actually use or see called: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`