# File permissions "Administrators: Full Control". Why isn't it always sufficient?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

Consider the following situation.

Let's say I have two interactive local user accounts registered on my machine: `Admin` (member of `Administrators` group) and `Alice` (member of `Users` group). Let's say on my hard drive I have a folder `Test` with the following security settings:

```
Owner : Alice
Permissions:
  System : Full Control
  Administrators: Full Control
  Alice : Full Control
```

Now, if I log in under `Admin` account and attempt to open the folder `Test`, Windows will initially refuse to do so. It will display a message box saying

```
"You don't currently have permissions to access this folder"
```

My first question is: why? I'm logged in as `Admin` - a member of `Administrators` group - and therefore I'm supposed to have full control of the folder. Why does Windows say that I don't currently have permissions?

Now, the aforementioned message box will also offer me the opportunity to "Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder". If I click "Continue", I'll be allowed to open folder `Test`. And, as a consequence of that, the security settings of `Test` will change to

```
Owner : Alice
Permissions:
  System : Full Control
  Administrators: Full Control
  Alice : Full Control
  Admin : Full Control
```

As you can see, Windows automatically added an extra entry `Admin: Full Control` to the list. After that I will be able to access `Test` without any restrictions. However, the above set of security permissions seems to be redundant to me. It already included `Administrators: Full Control` entry from the very beginning. Why wasn't that sufficient?

So, my second question is: why would Windows need an extra `Admin: Full Control` entry to finally give `Admin` that "full control".

What is the formal logic behind this behavior?

---

**Some clarifications**

Note, this question is not about my `Admin` account not being "all-powerful Administrator that can do whatever he wants". I don't expect my `Admin` account to be all-powerful at all. In fact, at the most basic level I don't care about any special rights of my `Admin` account. It is just *some* account that belongs to *some* group.

My question is about file system access rights granted through group membership.

Consider another example. Let's say I created some random user group called `Ugly Ducklings`. And I added regular users `Alice` and `Bob` to the `Ugly Ducklings` group.

Then I create folder `DucklingTest` with the following permissions

```
Owner : Alice
Permissions:
  Ugly Ducklings : Full Control
```

Now, if I log in as `Bob` I will indeed have full control over `DucklingTest` folder (!).

Why?

Is my `Bob` an all-powerful administrator? No. Is my `Bob` privileged in any way? No. Do I have to "elevate" `Bob` somehow, to perform access to `DucklingTest`? No.

So, why does `Bob` have full control over `DucklingTest` folder?

Easy. `Bob` has full control over `DucklingTest` folder because `Bob` is a member of `Ugly Ducklings` group and `Ugly Ducklings` group has been granted full control permissions over `DucklingTest`. End of story.

How come the same logic does not apply to `Admin` and `Administrators`? `Admin` is a member of `Administrators` group and `Administrators` group has been granted full control permissions over `Test` folder. What's missing here? What kind of extra "control" Windows is trying to enforce in this case by imposing what looks like *extra* restrictions on members of `Administrators` group?

Answer (score 3):

#### If I click "Continue", I'll be allowed to open folder Test

The following explains why Windows automatically adds an extra entry `Admin: Full Control to the list`.

> Assume that User Account Control (UAC) is enabled, and you use Windows
>   Explorer to access a folder for which you don’t have Read permissions.
>
> Additionally, the folder is not marked by both the Hidden and System
>   attributes. In this situation, Windows Explorer displays a dialog box
>   that prompts you with the following:
>
> "You don’t currently have permission to access this folder. Click
>   Continue to permanently get access to this folder"
>
> Note:
>
> - In Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, the second sentence does not include the word “permanently”; it just says “Click Continue to
>     get access to this folder.”
>
> You then have the option to click Continue or Cancel. (Continue is
>   selected by default.)
>
> - If you click Continue, UAC tries to obtain administrative rights on your behalf.
> - Depending on the UAC security settings that control the behavior of the UAC elevation prompt, and on whether you are a member of the
>     Administrators group, you may be prompted for consent or for
>     credentials.
> - Or, you may not be prompted at all. If UAC can obtain administrative rights, a background process will change the permissions on the
>     folder, and on all its subfolders and files, to grant your user
>     account access to them.
> - In Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, the background process grants your user account Read and Execute permissions. In later
>     versions of Windows, this process grants your user account Full
>     Control.
>
> This behavior is by design. But because the typical pattern with UAC
>   elevation is to run an instance of the elevated program with
>   administrative rights, users may expect that by clicking Continue,
>   this will generate an elevated instance of Windows Explorer and not
>   make permanent changes to file system permissions.
>
> However, this expectation is not possible, as Windows Explorer’s
>   design does not support the running of multiple process instances in
>   different security contexts in an interactive user session.
>
> If UAC is disabled, UAC elevation is not possible.
>
> - All programs that are run by members of the Administrators group, including Windows Explorer, always have administrative rights.
> - Therefore, administrators do not need to use elevation to access resources that require administrative rights.
>
> For example, if a folder grants access only to the Administrators
>   group and the System account, an administrator can browse it directly
>   without being prompted to alter the folder’s permissions.
>
> - If the user does not have Read permissions, Windows Explorer displays the dialog box that was described earlier.
> - However, if UAC is disabled, Windows cannot request administrative credentials on behalf of the user through a UAC elevation prompt.
> - Therefore, Windows will not start a background process with administrative permissions in order to change file system permissions.
>
> However, if the user clicks Continue and the folder’s current security
>   descriptor grants the user permission to both read and change the
>   object’s permissions, Windows will start the background process in the
>   user’s current security context and modify the folder’s permissions to
>   grant the user greater access, as described earlier.
>
> The user may have permission to read and change the object’s
>   permissions from object ownership or from the object’s access control
>   list (ACL).

Source [When you click Continue for folder access in Windows Explorer, your user account is added to the ACL for the folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950934)

---

#### I'm logged in as Admin - a member of Administrators group

> and therefore I'm supposed to have full control of the folder. Why does Windows say that I don't currently have permissions?

The account called `Admin` is **not** the built-in `Administrator` account (which is named `Administrator`).

The built-in Administrator account doesn't require privilege elevation, while users you create and put in Administrators group do (assuming UAC hasn't been disabled).

If you want to do something that need Adminstrators privileges using an account created (for example `Admin`) and placed in Administrators group you will have to either:

- Confirm the privilege elevation when requested, or
- Run as Administrator by right clicking the application and selecting the option.

---

#### An Administrator is not THE Administrator

> A user was trying to set the owner of a file to "Administrator." The user was unable to do this even though he was logged on as an administrator. Why won’t the system let an administrator change the owner of a file to Administrator? Don’t administrators have permission to take ownership of files?

...

> **So do you know the difference between Administrator and Administrators?**
>
> Administrator is an account.
>
> - If a permission or privilege is granted
>     to Administrator, it can be done only by someone logged in with the
>     Administrator account, that is, the account whose name defaults to
>     Administrator (in English).
>
> Administrators, on the other hand, is a group.
>
> - If you are a member of
>     the Administrators group of a machine, you have been granted
>     administrator privileges on that machine.
> - It is membership in the
>     Administrators group that people refer to when they say things like
>     "I’m an administrator on this machine."
> - The use of an indefinite
>     article ("an") as opposed to a definite article ("the") highlights
>     that the user is just one of many administrators.
>
> Things are more ambiguous when people say something like "I’m running
>   as administrator." This could mean either they are running as the
>   Administrator account or that they are running with an account that is
>   a member of the Administrators group.
>
> Once you understand this difference, it becomes clear why the user I
>   mentioned earlier was unable to reassign ownership of the file.
>
> - The
>     user was logged on with an account that belongs to the Administrators
>     group—but not with the Administrator account itself.
> - Let’s call the
>     user’s account "Bob." The SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege privilege is
>     assigned to members of the Administrators group, allowing members of
>     this group to assign ownership to themselves. However, this privilege
>     does not let members assign ownership to somebody else.
> - In this
>     example, Bob could assign ownership of the file to Bob. But he is
>     mistakenly trying to assign ownership to Administrator and since Bob
>     is not the same as Administrator, the operation fails.
>
> The user needs to log on with the Administrator account and take
>   ownership of the files from there. In this case, the Administrator is
>   assigning ownership to himself. (Alternatively, Bob could enable
>   `SeRestorePrivilege` before setting the owner.
>
> - This method is somewhat
>     unorthodox, however, since `SeRestorePrivilege` is intended to be used
>     by backup restore programs.)

Source [An Administrator Is Not the Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.03.windowsconfidential.aspx)

---

#### Further reading

- [What is the difference between my admin account and the “Administrator”?](https://superuser.com/questions/492976/what-is-the-difference-between-my-admin-account-and-the-administrator)

Comment: Sorry, this does not look relevant at all. You apparently decided my question is about my `Admin` not being "admin enough". No, this is not what the question is about. Not even close. The question is about file system permissions and their operation with no relation to any "super-rights" supposedly assigned to administrators. I can create a folder owned by `Alice` and grant `Users : Full Control` rights on that folder. Under such rights user `Bob` (also a members of `Users`) will be able to freely enter that folder. And `Bob` is not even a member of `Administrators` group!

Comment: @AnT Then please clarify your question. As it stands, your question does not mention `Users : Full Control` at all. What your question does say is that `Admin` doesn't initially have the correct permissions. That is what my answer explains. `Admin : Full Control` is **not** the same as `Administrators: Full Control`. `Admin` is a user. `Administrators` is a group.

Comment: @AnT "If you want to do something that need Adminstrators privileges using an account created (for example Admin) and placed in Administrators group you will have to either:

    Confirm the privilege elevation when requested, or

    Run as Administrator by right clicking the application and selecting the option.
"

Comment: @AnT "Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder" is Confirming the privilege elevation when requested as I stated in my answer.

Comment: If I grant `Users : Full Control` permission, `Bob` will be able to open the folder because `Bob` is a member of `Users` group. Then why `Admin` (who is a members of `Administrators` group) cannot open the same folder in the very same way through the same logic? Again, I don't care how "powerful" (or "powerless" my `Admin` is). All I care about is that my `Admin` is a member of `Administrators`. Why the logic that allowed `Bob` to enter does not apply to `Admin`? Why a "mere-mortal" group `Users`(and therefore `Bob`) seems to be less restricted (in group rights) than `Administrators` group?

Comment: No, clicking "Continue to permanently..." does not perform privilege elevation in its normal sense. It simply performs automatic update of security permissions, as described above. Privilege elevation is always temporary. What happens in this case is permanent.

Comment: I can create a group named, say, `Ugly Ducklings`. And I can give `Ugly Ducklings` full control over folder `Test` (and no one else). After than any member of `Ugly Ducklings` will be able to freely open that folder and do absolutely anything to it. Why does some random group `Ugly Ducklings` work "as expected", while `Administrators` group doesn't work that way?

Comment: @AnT Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding through experience:

`Administrators` is a privileged group.

When you log in as an `Administrators` member, some applications do not run in an elevated `**Administrator**` level.  Applications like **explorer** and iexplore are running at the `Users` permission level therefore if you access a folder where your only right is being a member of `Administrators`, you have to jump through an extra hoop to gain elevated access to the folder structure.

Case in point is if you try to get the size of a user profile folder where your only right is as an `Administrators` member, you cannot get the size of the folder contents because you have not gained that right yet.  You must first open the folder to jump through the elevation hoop and get that permission first because **explorer** is running at the `Users` permission level.  You will see the same thing sometimes when dealing with viewing file permission and can't see them.  You will sometimes see a button to click to elevate the window's permission level so you can view them.

Now if you run **explorer** as an `**Administrator**`, I believe you no longer have to jump through that elevation hoop (I can't remember if that actually works at the moment, it's been a while).

I hope this helps.