# You don't currently have permission to access this folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I'm trying to understand an error on Windows 7 Professional Edition:

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder

This error shows two buttons, `Continue` and `Cancel`. The folder is `C:\windows\system32\tasks`, but it could be any system folder.

I'm in an Admin account. I click `Cancel`, open Explorer and check effective permissions on `C:\windows\system32\tasks` for the Admin account.

Everything is checked.

So why do I get the "You don't currently have permission to access this folder" error when trying to open the folder?

And what permissions does the Continue button set that hasn't already been set?

Just trying to understand how this works, and eventually to set permissions on a task so a non-privileged user can run it.

Comment: No Repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Comment: Can't reproduce it on W7 64 bit Enterprise.
I advise to change the owner of the folder: Security tab > Advanced > Owner > Edit > Tick the checkbox "Replace owner...", select owner and Apply.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to change the owner of anything in windows\system32, don't you think?

Comment: Related, possible dupe (?): http://superuser.com/questions/1006655/file-permissions-administrators-full-control-why-isnt-it-always-sufficient

Comment: More on [this search](http://superuser.com/search?q=%22You+don%27t+currently+have+permission+to+access+this+folder.%22+Is%3Aq) as well.