# How can I set folder permission for Administrators members without elevation (UAC)

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator, uac

I want to have a folder with access privilegs for all members of Administators group **without running in highest privilege mode / UAC elevation**.

If I just add "Administrators" in ACL, this does not work. Details can be found here: [File permissions "Administrators: Full Control". Why isn't it always sufficient?](https://superuser.com/questions/1006655/file-permissions-administrators-full-control-why-isnt-it-always-sufficient)

- Running accessing processes in elevated mode (or disabling UAC) is no option.
- Manually adding every member of Administrators to ACL (as Windows Explorer does when confirming dialog) is no option, either.

I could create my own "CustomAdministrators" group and add all members of Administrators there, but this is a maintenance problem.

Is there some other option (e.g. another built-in SID)?

Comment: Changing folder ACLs needs elevated permission. This is ok.

I want to allow read privilege on one folder for all admins (members of Administrators) without the need for privilege elevation. So I would like to use Administrators group the same way I can use other groups (e.g. Users) -- or something similar working.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think you are wrong. Test it or have a look at the superuser question I linked above. If you have privileges set for Administrators group you (as a member) will not have direct access. Windows explorer will give you an option to elevate and add your personal account to ACLs. An elevated process will have access, a non-elevated one won't. You can test this with cmd.exe.

Comment: Alright, I withdraw my comments, good luck.  I can no longer help you